# How to Open Links in a browser of a website Inside a Webviewer JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

I have this VBox holding a WebView container. What I can not figure out is how to make the WebViewer open links in a new tab or window in any browser not Viewing it on the program.

```
@FXML private VBox WebViewer;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    webEngine.load("http://google.com/");

    WebViewer.getChildren().addAll(browser);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've figured this out by now, but the way I would have done it involves using the special JavaScript API in the WebEngine to call a java method and open it that way.

Create a class, like this one:

```
public class eagler {
    public void open(String url) {
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);
    }
}
```

Then, add this before your `webengine.load` method:

```
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov,
                    State oldState, State newState) {   
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                            win.setMember("eagler", new eagler());
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

Now, whenever you want to open an external page...

```
<button onclick="eagler.open('http://bitly.com/98K8eH')">Click Me</button>
```